# How I can extract field to xml in Php?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml with more subcategory.
I want extract in Php the “long_name” where type is “adminkstrative_area_level_3”
How I can do?
This is my xml https://ibb.co/fY27bJ

I tried but don’t work

```
   <? 
$string_data = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=41.51,15.16&key=AIzaSyClG_vc2nkQCzXqvDzW1maPrUWLyADI7xI";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string_data);
$citta = (string) $xml->result[0]->address_component[3]->long_name;

echo "<p>".$citta."</p>";
?>
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and add the actual xml instead of an image.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I can’t add image. I linked it https://ibb.co/nzPmLd .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `geoname` in `$xml-> name;`

Try it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string_data);
$citta = (string)$xml->geoname->name;
echo $citta;
```

[Demo Php](https://3v4l.org/MpKqP)

If you want to loop through mulitple items you could use:

```
foreach ($xml->geoname as $item) {
    echo $item->name;
}
```

Update:

For the updated part you could use the same technique:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=41.51,15.16&key=AIzaSyClG_vc2nkQCzXqvDzW1maPrUWLyADI7xI");

foreach ($xml->result as $item) {
    if ((string)$item->type === "administrative_area_level_3") {
        echo $item->address_component->long_name;
    }
}
```

Or by index `[1]`:

```
echo $xml->result[1]->address_component->long_name;
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my website I don’t see nothing .. why?

Comment: @user9711797 Are you sure this is right url? `"http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=41.157&lng=16.41548&username=manu2424` Do you echo your value? Or could you do a `var_dump($citta);`

Comment: url is correct because if you see this url you can see xml. I want only print $citta

Comment: What do you see then you load `http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=41.157&lng=16.41548&username=manu2424` in your browser? I get `<status message="invalid username" value="10"/>` Try [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Comment: omg.. now I see that service is unaviable.. do you know other service that give me a xml link for have name of City by coordinates?

Comment: I don't think the service is unavailable but the username is invalid. You might check your credentials.

Comment: If you want I have update my principal topic.. help me please :(

Comment: @user9711797 I have added an update to my answer.

Comment: thanks so much... but in 3v4l.org there are more error and warning and not work

Comment: Ok work very well! But it possibile concert this code in JavaScript. Because I need use the coordinates by JavaScript in a variable Php to put in link of google api.